# Do I need to have an @property here?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwindow

Basically I want to be able to access the UIApplication delegate's `window` property all the way through my class, so I want to reference it with an iVar.

To this end I don't want to "own" it, just reference it.

So therefore should I just put a variable reference in the .h file?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MessageView : UIView {
    UILabel *messageLabel;
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabel;

@end
```

Or should I set the property there too?

I'm sceptical because the property would be `nonatomic, retain`, but I don't want to retain it, unless I actually do and I'm just being thick! :p

The purpose of having the window object is just to be able to add subviews to it, rather than the current view controller's view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow *window
```

Then you are not retaining it.

Given the window *should* exist for the lifetime of your app there is no real need to retain it as it's already being retained by your app delegate.

Having a property in the first place in this scenario is nothing more than syntactic sugar

```
someclass.window = self.window; // Using a property
```

is much more succinct than

```
window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].window; // Using an iVar
```

Comment: Many thanks. :) assign it is. That's what I thought you see, that I didn't need to own it, as its already owned. :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well you actually do want to retain the `UIWindow`. New projects by default retain it and there is nothing wrong with that.</strike> I see that `MessageView` is inheriting directly from [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and that has a window property that is set once it is added to a window(or a subview of a window). Also look at `willMoveToWindow:` and `didMoveToWindow`. Now never think that you can not create a property just because you do not want to retain something because that is what the `assign` keyword is for.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MessageView : UIView {
    UILabel *messageLabel;
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, you do not.

Whenever you use any of the `UIWindow` [Make Key Window](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW7) methods (as you probably is doing inside your `AppDelegate`), such as

> – makeKeyAndVisible 
>   – makeKeyWindow

The window becomes available from all your application just by using the `UIApplication's` [keyWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW32) property.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

So, there is no need for a property or a retain in your `AppDelegate` or anywhere else, as it will be retained by your application class.

OBS: The property is commonly placed in your `AppDelegate` as the application template from XCode used the interface builder and an IBOutlet to instantiate the `UIWindow`. So, if your are creating your window by hand, there is no need for a property there.